# Charles not decrypting SOCKS traffic?

Tags: proxy, socks, charles-proxy

I have Charles installed and this is working fine (I can view encypted data to https websites and so on).

I have turned on `SOCKS proxy` and `enabled SSL Proxying` with location set to everything.

I also have `SocksCap` installed and connect to the `Charles SOCKS proxy`. run the application in `SocksCap` and all the connections turn nicely up in Charles (3.11.4) as `socket://xx.xx.xx.xx:443.` as expected

However and this is the big problem.

The Data is still encrypted!

Why is this not decrypted by Charles?

Best regards,
Erik

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it? Certificate is installed